# req.header no me devuelve el valor del header, retorna un undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Cuando logueo el req, me devuelve el header con valor null
[image: Aqui esta la funcion con la que deveria generarme un token y devolverme su valor, pero me devulve undefined]

Comment: Buenas noches, veo que ya te han votado negativo, para evitar los votos negativos o incluso el cierre de la pregunta, te sugiero que leas [ask].
Lo ideal sería que no subas imágenes sino código, se suele subir lo que se conoce como mínimo código verificable ej: de front la llamada completa, de back el handler, información sobre librerías utilizadas para poder hacer las pruebas con lo que estás utilizando, etc... Esto nos permite poder hacer las pruebas pertinentes y ayudarte en el menor tiempo posible.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

En general se hace algo como lo siguiente:

**Del lado frontend:**
Si se hace una llamada se agrega en la misma

```
headers: {
authorization: "bearer token(token sería el que se generó anteriormente)"
}
```

Si se usa por ejemplo Insomnia se puede agregar en los headers **authorization** y en el **value** bearer + token generado.
Otra opción en Insomnia es ir a la flecha de **Auth** y marcar **bearer token**, aquí solo es necesario pegar el token en el campo que lo solicita.

**Del lado backend se podría hacer algo así:**

```
//Se obtiene el token, que recibe un string con la palabra bearer + token
const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];

//Se separan ambas palabras quedando el toquen en el índice 1 del array resultante  
const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');

//Se deposita el token obtenido en bearerToken
const bearerToken = bearer[1];
```

Luego se hace lo deseado con el, se puede hacer el verify y luego guardar el payload en req.auth o req.user para dejarlo disponible.

---

Otra opción es utilizar el middleware express-jwt que hace todo esto automático y deja disponible el payload del token en req.auth
Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt